# php web service cannot read my angular js key value

Tags: php, angularjs, web-services, api

I am using angularjs 1.6.4 version, I send my keys and values to php web service but my key and value does not read, I get result for in database stored at '0',  this is my angular js code,

```
        $scope.fav = {
            "userid":101,
            "favid":120
        }
        $http({
            method:"POST",
            url:apiurl+"addFavorites.php",
            data:JSON.stringify($scope.fav)
        }).then(function(data)
        {
            $scope.favorites = data.data;
            alert(data.data.message);
        });
```

this is my php rest api

```
include("../includes/db.php");

//creating response array
$response = array();

$request_method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if ($request_method == 'POST' && array_key_exists('HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD', $_SERVER)) {
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD'] == 'DELETE') {
      $request_method = 'DELETE';
    } else if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {
      $request_method = 'PUT';
    } else {
      throw new Exception("Unexpected Header");
    }
}

if($request_method == "POST"){

    //getting values
    $userid = isset($_POST['userid']) && $_POST['userid'] != '' ? trim($_POST['userid']) : "";
    $favid = isset($_POST['favid']) && $_POST['favid'] != '' ? trim($_POST['favid']) : "";

    if ($favid == 0) {
    $strupdate = mysql_query("insert into nr_favourites(UserProfileId,FavouriteUserProfileId,CreatedDate)Values('$userid','$favid',now())");
    }
    if ($favid != 0) {
        $sql = mysql_query("select * from nr_favourites where id=$favid");
        $rc = mysql_num_rows($sql);
        if ($rc != 0) {
            $strupdate = mysql_query("insert into nr_favourites(UserProfileId,FavouriteUserProfileId,CreatedDate)Values('$userid','$favid',now())");
        }
    }

    if ($strupdate) 
    {
        $response['error']=false;
        $response['message']='add favourites successfully!';
    }
    else
    {
        $response['error']=true;
        $response['message']='add favourites not successfully.';
    }

} else {
    $response['error']=true;
    $response['message']='You are not authorized';
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

those are my code, please help me to solve this error

Comment: Your question is AngularJS related, not Angular. Allow me to edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be saving strings to numerical fields.  When `JSON.stringify($scope.fav)` is called the numbers are converted to strings.

Here

`$userid = isset($_POST['userid']) && $_POST['userid'] != '' ? trim($_POST['userid']) : "";
$favid = isset($_POST['favid']) && $_POST['favid'] != '' ? trim($_POST['favid']) : "";`

since user_id and favid are strings they are set to empty strings every time.  My guess would be both

```
nr_favourites.UserProfileId
nr_favourites.FavouriteUserProfileId
```

are numerical fields which are receiving strings hence the 0 values.  Remove JSON.stringify() and save nulls rather than empty strings, this should take care of the issue.